# Are not Shri and Lakshmi name of one goddess?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, lakshmi, shukla-yajurveda

I've read that in Shukla Yajurveda Shri and Laxmi are two consort of Aditya (sun god) I'm pretty sure the Aditya here is Vishnu. But aren't Shri and Laxmi name of just one goddess?

[Google book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1TLsJW-WInIC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=two+wives+of+aditya+aitareya+brahmana&source=bl&ots=iAzIICgVa3&sig=QbD7k9zykZ95VcSlKWgRRqUs-LU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD5umt8ubYAhVBu48KHUW_AEwQ6AEwAXoECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=two%20wives%20of%20aditya%20aitareya%20brahmana&f=false)

[image]

Comment: i think i answered all of your queries do you want me to add something more?

Answer (score 3):

> भद्रैषां
>   लक्ष्मी र्निहिताधि वाचि
>   bhadraiṣāṁ
>   lakṣmī rnihitādhi vāci
>
> "an auspicious fortune
>   is attached to their
>   words"
>
> **— Rig Veda, x.71.2,
>   Translated by John
>   Muir**

In Atharvaveda , Lakshmi evolves into a
complex concept with plural
manifestations. Book 7, Chapter
115 of Atharva Veda describes
the plurality, asserting that a
hundred Lakshmis are born with
the body of a mortal at birth,
some good, punya (virtuous) and
auspicious, while others bad,
paapi (evil) and unfortunate. The
good are welcomed, while the
bad urged to leave.

**The Hymns of the Atharvaveda: Book VII: HYMN CXV A charm against Misfortune**

> source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/avbook07.htm

The word lakshmi simply translates as 'fortune' simply i think nothing complicated.
And sometimes symbolic in vedic times as in above verse of rigveda.

> Granting us riches, **Savitar! golden-
>   banded**, send thou away
>   from us to other regions
>   **That Fortune** who, flying,
>   abominable, hath, as a creeper
>   climbs
>   **— Atharvaveda: Book VII: HYMN CXV**

And here while searching word shri or lakshmi in shukla yajurveda i did not got any appropriate  result but the word lakshmi in vedic times denotes fortune as in above verses

http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/yajur/white_yajurveda.asp

Comment: yes lakshmi in most places is used as prosperity and affluence and not in the sense of Vishnu paTnI

Comment: your answer is well appreciated - but let us not go by dates given by western indologist. Sanskrit and its predecessor Prakrit existed much before the accepted date of Rig Veda about 4000 years ago.

Comment: @Suresh Ramaswamy i take that(paragraph) from wikipedia thats why. Now its okay.;)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Sri sukta calls laxmi as Vishnu patni.

Comment: @AnubhavJha can you quote the.rik ?

Comment: @Rakesh joshi http://greenmesg.org/stotras/lakshmi/sri_suktam.php

Comment: @AnubhavJha only fifteen plus one.riks are part of sri suktam. Lakshmi suktam is later day. Its not part of vedas.

Comment: It is not in rigveda but as an appendix.
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Śrī_Sūkta)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi ￼
"
ōm mahādevyai ca vidmahe viṣṇupatnī ca dhīmahi,
tanno lakṣmīḥ pracodayāt.

We commune ourselves with the Great Goddess, and meditate on the Consort of Vishnu. May that Lakshmi direct us (to the Great Goal).
"

Comment: @RakeshJoshi above are the last lines of Sri suktam from rigveda.

Comment: http://www.puja.net/wordpress/sri-suktam-rig-veda-mantra-for-lakshmi/

Comment: @Anubhav Jha I already told sri sukta is an appendix to rigveda some dieties not some many were not present in vedas.

This is rigveda here:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/ 

There is devi-sukta but not consist tridevis or even vedic goddesses.— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devīsūkta 

btw vedic goddess consist ushas saraswati and others.

you must see rigvedic dities:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigvedic_deities

Comment: @Fiercelord westerners believe in this "interpolation" "appendix" idea, most orthodox hindus do not believe in timeline given by westerners, according to tradition ved vyas divided Vedas 5000 years ago. Along with writing purans and vedanta sutras. Sri sukta is present in rig Veda that is enough proof. Westerners also say that purusha sukta sutra is later interpolation, but most people do not believe that.

Comment: @AnubhavJha such mantras exist for all deities even for modern gods and saints. They were created on the basis of main Gayatri mantra.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi but there laxmi is called consort of Vishnu. This is from Sri sukta of rigveda.

Comment: @AnubhavJha no sir its not. Its laxmi gayatri added later. Sri suktam ends at तां म आवह जातवेदो लक्ष्मीमनपगामिनीम् ।
यस्यां हिरण्यं प्रभूतं गावो दास्योऽश्वान् विन्देयंपूरुषानहम् ॥१५॥

Comment: @RakeshJoshi later as how late? Aren't the full mantras revealed to a seer. The mantra comes with a laxmi gayatri.

Comment: @AnubhavJha its usually chanted with laxmi gayatri but its not technically vedic mantra. Gayatri mantras are there for all deities even non vedic and also for saints. They are created on a prototype based on gayatri mantra. But you are right that S Suktam is certainly part of vedas. Even though it's in khila.kaanda yet its as important as others unlike fierce lord suggested. I have got wonderful results from it over years. You can do laxmi gayatri and laxmi suktam no.harm in it. But i am just saying for understanding that actual suktam.is fifteen verses. Sri is also meant as fertile soil wealt

Comment: @Anubhav Jha there is nothing relating a lot to western sri sukta is not present in rigveda so what you think for what i given the online rigveda translation even download hindi translations it is not **present**. 
And purans and vedas are diffrent if not then why rigveda never mentions it shruti and smriti are diffrent things.
And the word later added is used because finding what's true and what added.
And purush sukta is present in book 10 but present **it is present in rigveda**.

Answer (score 2):

The dhyanamantra of Lakshmi mentions श्रियं त्रैलोक्यमातरम्. So Shree is one with Lakshmi. Her beejamantra is also श्रीं which makes the conclusion clear.