# Is devi lakshmi called wife of Lord vishnu in Rig Veda khillani sukta?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, lakshmi

Goddess lakshmi is considered wife of Lord vishnu and I have also checked verse in Sri suktam calling devi lakshmi wife of Lord vishnu but that could be later addition.so I want to know is goddess Lakshmi called wife of Lord vishnu in the original Rig Veda khillani Sri suktam?

Comment: This is Sri suktam from all the verses of all four vedas, here there are multiple references to Sri being vishnu's wife http://greenmesg.org/stotras/lakshmi/sri_suktam.php

Comment: according to wiki sri - lakshmi being vishnu's consort is late: "The goddess Śrī appears in several earlier vedic hymns, and is the personification of auspicious and royal qualities.[1] Śrī Sūkta is perhaps the first text in which the homology between Śrī and Lakṣmī is drawn, and the goddesses are further associated with the god of fire, Agni.[3] Since the later epic period (ca 400 CE), Śrī-Lakṣmī is particularly associated with Viṣṇu as his wife or consort.[5]"

Comment: "calling devi lakshmi wife of Lord vishnu but that could be later addition" What do you mean by this? Lakshmi is not not Vishnu's wife or Vishnu is not Lakshmi's husband? If it does call or doesn't call, what difference would that make?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma don't take SK wrong in vedas laxmi was translated as fortune in those days and was related to diffrent dieties the sanskrit word laxmi means "fortune" in vedas See my answer here:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/are-not-shri-and-lakshmi-name-of-one-goddess/23579#23579 (May be duplicate)

Comment: @Anubhav jha sri sukta is not present in rigveda may be an appendix to rigveda.

Comment: @SK all the gods are associated with agni in rig Veda, agni is used for invoking a diety. Also I do not believe in timeline given by westerners and their weird explanations, they claim everything to be later interpolation to which they disagree with.

Comment: @Fiercelord you might believe that Sri is fortune according to timeline given by westerners for rigveda, but traditionally all the first 3 Vedas are said to be composed in satyuga and yajur Veda verses do call laxmi wife of visnu.

Comment: @Anubhav jha how much time i have to tell you that from where the westerners came now niether in yajurveda it is present and if you are talking i have reminded you how many times that NOT PRESENT IN RIGVEDA  get me any rigveda book book 10 is last book in rigveda everywhere and there is no more book i given you link to rigveda to check that SRI SUKTA IS NOT PRESENT IN RIGVEDA OR ANY OTHER VEDAS!!!!. if sri sukta is present in any rigveda samhita get me it otherwise stop misleading people by saying all puranic gods are present in vedas bro vedas and purans are diffrent thing.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  I Mean that is goddess lakshmi being wife of Lord vishnu is found in sri suktam of Rig Veda khillani?because some people say it is not found in khillani s,I want to know that.

Comment: @Fiercelord read the sukta from above link.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda there is some confusion because Sri suktam is often chanted with laxmi suktam which is NON VEDIC it starts with ya shuchi prayatobhootva... and ends with lakshmi gayatri however its not part of veda but man made hymn... vedic verses are only 15 in number.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I Got To Know,I was searching this In YouTube where a video states originally sri suktam has 15 suktas while the 16th sukta stating Lord vishnu being consort of goddess lakshmi is a shanti mantra of Sri suktam and probaly a later addition around 400 bc and Sri suktam is expected to be older then 400 bc.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi you do not believe that laxmi is wife of Lord Vishnu, even though Lord Vishnu is called laxmi narayana

Comment: @AnubhavJha lakshmi and sri not always same. In sri suktam sri is denoted also as fertile soil and affluence etc. You are mmixing vedic and puranic a bit

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Sri sukta called laxmi,  progeny of kardama, story of kardama being father of incarnation of laxmi is given in puranas, laxmi is pictured with elephant and lotus another thing common with purana, she is called golden coloured, laxmi is also hold coloured, Sri is diety laxmi of puranas. Stop trying to make a wedge between puranas and Vedas, puranas were written by vyasa on commentary of vedas.

Comment: @AnubhavJha first you stop trying to spread sectarian propaganda here. Read sri suktam first ... Lakshmi is not the progeny of kardama but kardama and chikleeta are.progeny of Lakshmi...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi wow! LoL pot calling kettle black, have you ever read your own questions or answers, where you write about "Lord indra", you are more secterian trying to devide Vedas and puranas. Also the translation of Sri suktam I read, it said Sri **has** progeny of kardama, it's not mentioned if she is daughter or mother, but it does say that there is relation.

Comment: @AnubhavJha there is no HAS in your comment. Vedas and puranas are already divided no one can compare them they are different class of scriptures. Its foolish to compare both

Comment: @RakeshJoshi it's known that Vedas and puranas are different, because shruti is explained differently with multiple meaning, while smritis are considered records, what I'm trying to say is that you are trying to divide the identity of laxmi and other deities in Vedas and puranas.

Comment: @AnubhavJha the question is solely related to sri suktam i.e the fifteen verses. No one.is questioning goddess Lakshmi we all.are.devotee of her right. But limit it to sri suktam.and vedas and not divert to non vedic texts

Answer (score 1):

Yes but in later verses :—optional to go through this link ([https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Śrī_Sūkta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%AB_S%C5%ABkta))

Why i am saying this check it out verses which goddess lakshmi as lord vishnu's consort are not part of verses see these are those last verses :—

> Invoke for me O Agni, that Goddess
>   Lakshmi, who is ever unfailing, being
>   blesses by whom I shall win wealth in
>   plenty, cattle, servants, horses and men.
>
> We commune ourselves with the Great
>   Goddess, and meditate on the **consort of
>   Vishnu**; may that Lakshmi direct us (to
>   the Great Goal). Om May there be Peace,
>   Peace, Peace.

While the sukta end with this verse:—

> **(13-14)** Invoke for me, O Agni, Lakshmi
>   who shines like gold, is brilliant like the
>   sun, who is powerfully fragrant, who
>   wields the rod of suzerainty, who is the
>   form of supreme rulership, who is radiant
>   with ornaments and is the goddess of
>   wealth. Invoke for me O Agni, the Goddess
>   Lakshmi who shines like gold, blooms like
>   the moon, who is fresh with anointment
>   (of fragrant scent), who is adorned with
>   the lotuses (lifted up by celestial
>   elephants in the act of worship), who is
>   the presiding deity of nourishment, who
>   is yellow in colour, and who wears
>   garlands of lotuses.
>
> source:— http://www.divyajivan.org/ashtalakshmi/sri_suktam.htm

**So thirteen(13) and fourteen(14) are last verses after that they are later added which are not part of original sukta verses but later added** it is upto your belief that you aknowledge these later verses or not if you have read upnishads there is a starting prayer which really from where it is taken do not exist like isha upnishad is chapter 40 of yajurveda but the starting prayer is not present in yajurveda so it is upto you to aknowledge that last prayer of sri sukta as authentic or in-authentic now its about belief **but the last verses are not part of sukta**.

(MY INTENTION IS NOT TO HURT ANYBODY FEELINGS THAT 'S WHY I LEAVE THE ANSWER AS SUBJECT TO PERSONAL BELIEF.)

Comment: This does not answers my question,I just want to know that does the Rig Veda khillani s sri suktam call goddess lakshmi wife of Lord vishnu?

Comment: @fierce this verse is not part of veda but added with the suktam at the end so please modify the answer

Comment: @Rakesh joshi done just have a look is it ok i do not want to hurt anybody feelings so it is up to us to aknowledge these verses or not.